# how to add a CheckAll button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to add a CheckAll button to the following....
[what I have right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNHkB.png)
Every thing works if I check those boxes etc, but I'm struggling to find a way to add a checkbox that selects all,  I have tried several examples , I can get the entry to show up but nothing happens.

Here is the file I am thinking the checkAll should go into.   Please give me some guidance, be detailed please, took me forever to get to this point.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>List</title>
<script language="javascript" src="client.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
.even { background-color: gainsboro; color:#101010; }
.odd { background-color: white; color:#101010; }
.even:hover {background-color: cadetblue}
.odd:hover {background-color: cadetblue}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<form name="frmUser" method="post" action="">
<div style="width:500px;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" width="750" class="tblListForm">
<tr class="listheader">
<td></td>
<td><b>Username</b></td>
<td><b>fqdn</b></td>
<td><b>Status</b></td>
<td><b>Created</b></td>
</tr>
<?php
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
if($i%2==0)
$classname="even";
else
$classname="odd";

?>
<tr class="<?php if(isset($classname)) echo $classname;?>">
<!-- <td><input type="radio" name="xyxy[]" value="<?php echo $row["hostid"]; ?>" ></td> -->
<td><input type="checkbox" name="xyxy[]" value="<?php echo $row["hostid"]; ?>" ></td>
<td><?php echo $row["owner"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["host"]; ?>.<?php echo $row["domain"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["status"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["timestamp"]; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
<tr class="listheader">
<td colspan="4"><input type="button" name="x" value="Get"  onClick="setmyclientAction();" >
&nbsp<input type=reset value="Clear selection"> 
</td>
<input type="button" name="x" value="Get"  onClick="setmyclientAction();" >&nbsp<input 
type=reset value="Clear selection">


</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think instead of creating a button, you should add a checkbox. And `onclick` check/uncheck all other checkboxes. I have created a demo(removing the `php` of course) also I've used `jquery`. See if this works for you. ↓↓

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<title>List</title>
<script language="javascript" src="client.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
.even { background-color: gainsboro; color:#101010; }
.odd { background-color: white; color:#101010; }
.even:hover {background-color: cadetblue}
.odd:hover {background-color: cadetblue}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<form name="frmUser" method="post" action="#">
<div style="width:500px;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" width="750" class="tblListForm">
<tr class="listheader">
<td><input type="checkbox" onclick="$('input[name*=\'xyxy\']').prop('checked', this.checked);"></td>
<td><b>Username</b></td>
<td><b>fqdn</b></td>
<td><b>Status</b></td>
<td><b>Created</b></td>
</tr>
<!--<?php
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
if($i%2==0)
$classname="even";
else
$classname="odd";

?>-->
<tr class="classname">

<td><input type="checkbox" name="xyxy[]" value="1>" ></td>
<td>owner</td>
<td>host domain</td>
<td>status</td>
<td>timestamp</td>
</tr>

<tr class="classname">

<td><input type="checkbox" name="xyxy[]" value="2>" ></td>
<td>owner</td>
<td>host domain</td>
<td>status</td>
<td>timestamp</td>
</tr>
<!--<?php
$i++;
}
?>-->
<tr class="listheader">
<td colspan="4"><input type="button" name="x" value="Get"  onClick="setmyclientAction();" >
&nbsp;<input type=reset value="Clear selection"> 
</td>
<input type="button" name="x" value="Get"  onClick="setmyclientAction();" >&nbsp;<input 
type=reset value="Clear selection">


</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</body></html>
```